# Turn MySQL query into Percona pt-archiver string

Tags: mysql, sql, percona

How to express this in pt-archiver?

```
DELETE * FROM Table1 JOIN ON Table1.id=Table2.id WHERE Table2.id>=1;
```

I cannot find any possibility to join Table1 and Table2 within a string of pt-archiver. I tried this but the join string to Table2 is missing:

```
pt-archiver --source h=127.0.0.1,D=db,t=Table1 --purge --where 'Table2.id >= 1'
```

Please provide me some of your ideas.

Comment: pt-archiver doesn't seem to support the multi table case. If you want to optimaze your query, i think split the large DELETE into smaller ones. like `Table2.id>=20000000` ... then `Table2.id>=1000000` ..

Comment: Yes, I know that it could work, but if I go this way the server should be controlled manually for overloading issues and adjusted in emergency case. I found some solution on Percona homepage, as follows: `pt-archiver --source h=host,D=db,t=child --purge
\
--where 'EXISTS(SELECT
*
FROM parent WHERE col=child.col AND child.col>=1)'`. This could work, but I am not confident how and where the parent table is to be declared. Some ideas?

Comment: Probably like this??
`pt-archiver --source h=localhost,D=db,t=Table1 --purge \ --where 'EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id=Table1.id AND Table2.id>=1)'`

Comment: Try it with  `--dry-run`. this option show you what the cmd will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done tasks like what you describe, where I used pt-archiver to archive rows that must also be joined to another table.

> ```
> pt-archiver --source h=host,D=db,t=child --purge \ 
> --where 'EXISTS(SELECT * FROM parent WHERE col=child.col AND child.col>=1)'.
> ```
>
> This could work, but I am not confident how and where the parent table is to be declared. Some ideas?

You declare exactly one table in the source DSN for pt-archiver. That's the `child` table in this example.

You don't declare the `parent` table in the pt-archiver options. It's referenced only in the subquery you spell out in your `--where` option, exactly as in your example above.